# Knockout-validation group not working as expected while finding length of errors?

Tags: validation, knockout.js

I have a observable in my function and i just want to apply `required` validation to it . so i done like this

**View model:**

```
self.textareadata = ko.observable().extend({required:true});

var errors = ko.validation.group(self.textareadata);
```

On button click i am trying to fire up the validation like

```
self.click = function()
{
if(errors().length <=0)  
{//post data}
else
{errors.showAllMessages();}
}
```

// i tried `errors.length` but its failing me i.e length always `zero` .

Using the above if condition on button click if i dont have any data in my text area control i get the message `this field is required` but when i enter something(automatically messages clear's) and again click means here i am stuck i.e `else` condition firing not expected `if` .

So debugged and checked i.e i can find a  index[0] of null value . This i making my if condition fail .

I try `validatedobservable` if i use multiple observable validation but as it's a single one i want to do it by `group` .

Fiddle attached click [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/5sV5B/7/)

Anything i'm missing here & Help is appreaciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide array in group

```
self.errors = ko.validation.group([self.textareadata]);
```

Then use it like this

```
self.click = function()
{
    if(self.errors().length == 0)  
    {
        //post data
    }else{
        errors.showAllMessages();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting count one even if i enter something in textarea . any idea ? but as mentioned in my observation with index[0] data as null .

Comment: i have updated. Sorry my mistake i need to use this `self.errors.length` instead of `self.errors().length`. See the brackets with `errors`. [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/5sV5B/11/)

Comment: still it doesn't solve my scare . now always value is `ZERO` and it will never come to else condition

Comment: as far as i know group needs array which you are not providing. `ko.validation.group([self.textarea])` the use `self.errors().length]`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5sV5B/13/)

Comment: oh i see . glad you mentioned it . if you can please update the commented answer i can mark it so someone can catch up later to your answer .